# Tomcat starts but exits immidiately

Tags: linux, tomcat

I would like to setup a tomcat server.

Everytime i want to check the server status i get an error message

```
[Unit]
Description=Tomcat servlet container
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking

User=tomcat
Group=tomcat

Environment="JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java"
Environment="JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/urandom"

Environment="CATALINA_BASE=/opt/tomcat"
Environment="CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat"
Environment="CATALINA_PID=/opt/tomcat/temp/tomcat.pid"
Environment="CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms2048m -Xmx8192m -server -XX:+UseParallelGC"

ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
ExecStop=/opt/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

[image: journalctl note]

I tend to think it has to do something with userrights, but i am not sure.

Comment: Read tomcats error log.

Comment: And please don't post screenshots of text you could just copy&paste.

Comment: Not sure if it's related but in the past, I saw some problems with tomcat and systemd related to read-only file system: We had to add `ReadWritePaths` directive for a directory to make it work.